# Office js barchart building

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

everyone.

Now I am going make barchart using officejs on powerpoint.
I am using now office 2016 and I can't make barchart using office js.
I tried so many times to make barchart following the tutorials.

If anyone has similar experience with it, please share your experience with code.

I am waiting for your reply.

Thanks.

```
PowerPoint.run(function (context) {
  var slide = context.presentation.slides.getActiveSlide();
  var content = slide.content;

  // Define the chart data
  var chartData = [
    { category: "Category 1", value: 10 },
    { category: "Category 2", value: 20 },
    { category: "Category 3", value: 15 },
    { category: "Category 4", value: 25 },
  ];

  // Create the chart data table
  var dataTable = content.addTable(chartData.length + 1, 2);
  var headers = dataTable.rows.getFirst().cells;
  headers.getFirst().text = "Category";
  headers.getLast().text = "Value";

  for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    var row = dataTable.rows.getItem(i + 1);
    var cells = row.cells;
    cells.getFirst().text = chartData[i].category;
    cells.getLast().text = chartData[i].value.toString();
  }

  // Create the chart
  var chartShape = content.shapes.addChart(Office.ChartType.ColumnClustered, dataTable, 100, 100, 400, 300);

  // Set chart title and axis titles
  var chart = chartShape.chart;
  chart.title.text = "Bar Chart";
  chart.axes.primaryCategoryAxis.title.text = "Categories";
  chart.axes.primaryValueAxis.title.text = "Values";

  return context.sync();
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

It doesn't work at all, only errors.

Comment: You need to tell us what the errors are.

Comment: Sometime, it says there is no such functions like getActiveslides.
Can you please let me know what I am trying is possible ?
I am trying to show native powerpoint bar chart using officejs.
If it is possible, can you please put your sample code for me?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no API called getActiveSlide. You need to be familiar with the [PowerPoint APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/powerpoint) to make an add-in. Are you using an AI to write your code? This is the kind of mistake that AIs often make. Don't do that. AIs make so many mistakes, you don't save any time in the long run.